# angularjs 1.4 bindToController undefined callback parameter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have been struggling with this for a couple of hours and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have the following directive:

```
module.directive('userFullTextSearchSelect', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {},
            templateUrl: 'views/users/user.full.text.search.select.html',
            controller: 'UserFullTextSearchSelectController',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            bindToController: {
                userChange: '&'
            }
        };
    }]);
```

and controller:

```
 module.controller('UserFullTextSearchSelectController', ['$q', 'UserFactory',
        function ($q, UserFactory) {

            var self = this;

            self.itemChanged = itemChanged;

            function itemChanged(user) {
                console.log('itemchanged' + user);
                self.change = user ? user.UserID.ID : null;
                if (self.change !== self.previousChange)
                    self.userChange(user);
                self.previousChange = self.change;
            };
        }]);
});
```

When calling self.userChange, the function in the parent view below gets called, however the parameter is undefined - where am I going wrong?

```
<div user-full-text-search-select user-change="userChanged(user)"></div>

function userChanged(user) { <----------- user is undefined
                console.log('user' + user);
                self.detail.filter.UserID = user ? user.UserID.ID : null;
                getData(1);
            };
```

Thanks,

Comment: Where is the user coming from? try printing the user in html. {{user}} and see what you get..

Comment: it was empty, I ended up fixing it by changing self.userChange(user) to self.userChange({ user: user }) in the controller and now all is well. Thanks for trying to help.